# Use shared library linked with a makefile

Tags: c++, linux, dll, makefile

I am trying to compile my program with the following make file. I found a template on the internet and I am trying to use it. I only modified things before `# Main entry point`

---

**The make file**

```
# Define executable name
BIN = CLI_DeskManager

# Define source files
SRCS = main.cpp shell.cpp

# Define header file paths
INCPATH = -I./ -I/usr/include/X11/exensions -I/usr/include/X11 -I/home/julien/Documents/DeskManagerDll

# Define the -L library path(s)
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/home/julien/Documents/DeskManagerDll

# Define the -l library name(s)
LIBS = -lX11 -lXext -Wl,--no-as-needed -lDeskManager -lpthread


# Only in special cases should anything be edited below this line
OBJS      = $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)
CXXFLAGS  = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=c++11 -pthread
DEP_FILE  = .depend


# Main entry point
#
all: depend $(BIN)


# For linking object file(s) to produce the executable
#
$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    @echo Linking $@
    @$(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@


# For compiling source file(s)
#
.cpp.o:
    @echo Compiling $<
    @$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $<


# For cleaning up the project
#
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)

distclean: clean
    $(RM) $(BIN)
    $(RM) $(DEP_FILE)


# For determining source file dependencies
#
depend: $(DEP_FILE)
    @touch $(DEP_FILE)

$(DEP_FILE):
    @echo Generating dependencies in $@
    @-$(CXX) -E -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $(SRCS) >> $(DEP_FILE)

ifeq (,$(findstring clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
ifeq (,$(findstring distclean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
-include $(DEP_FILE)
endif
endif
```

---

**The errors**

But I have a lot of errors like the following one

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
```

But [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134825/makefile-issue-in-eclipse-cdt) soru says that the important one is :

```
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [CLI_DeskManager] Error 1
```

---

**Additional informations**

I already successfully compiled it with Code::blocks, this is the build log.

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -std=c++11 -g -pthread    -I/usr/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/include/X11 -I../DeskManagerDll  -c /home/julien/Documents/CommandLineInterface_DeskManager/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -std=c++11 -g -pthread    -I/usr/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/include/X11 -I../DeskManagerDll  -c /home/julien/Documents/CommandLineInterface_DeskManager/shell.cpp -o obj/Debug/shell.o
g++ -L-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu  -o bin/Debug/CommandLineInterface_DeskManager obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/shell.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib  -lX11 -lXext -Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread  /home/julien/Documents/DeskManagerDll/bin/Debug/libDeskManagerDll.so
```

I found answers on StackOverflow but I don't understand them.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252551/linker-error-during-make), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528958/make-file-problem), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134825/makefile-issue-in-eclipse-cdt), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155601/makefile-main-o-isnt-created-but-compiling-is-ok).

---

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

---

**Update** after Lijat answer

Makefile after the recommended modification

```
# Define executable name
BIN = CLI_DeskManager

# Define source files
SRCS = main.cpp shell.cpp

# Define header file paths
INCPATH = -I./ -I/usr/include/X11/exensions -I/usr/include/X11 -I/home/julien/Documents/DeskManagerDll

# Define the -L library path(s)
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/home/julien/Documents/DeskManagerDll/bin/Debug


# Define the -l library name(s)
LIBS = -lX11 -lXext -Wl,--no-as-needed -lDeskManagerDll -lpthread


# Only in special cases should anything be edited below this line
OBJS      = $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)
CXXFLAGS  = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=c++11 -pthread
DEP_FILE  = .depend


# Main entry point
#
all: depend $(BIN)


# For linking object file(s) to produce the executable
#
$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    echo Linking $@
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@


# For compiling source file(s)
#
.cpp.o:
    echo Compiling $<
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $< -o $@


# For cleaning up the project
#
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)

distclean: clean
    $(RM) $(BIN)
    $(RM) $(DEP_FILE)


# For determining source file dependencies
#
depend: $(DEP_FILE)
    touch $(DEP_FILE)

$(DEP_FILE):
    echo Generating dependencies in $@
    -$(CXX) -E -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $(SRCS) >> $(DEP_FILE)

ifeq (,$(findstring clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
ifeq (,$(findstring distclean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
-include $(DEP_FILE)
endif
endif
```

Full make output. I am sorry for the fact that it is in french. There are only two different sentences that are translated in the first part of my question.

```
julien@julien-VirtualBox:~/Documents/CommandLineInterface_DeskManager$ make
touch .depend
echo Linking CLI_DeskManager
Linking CLI_DeskManager
g++  -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/home/julien/Documents/DeskManagerDll/bin/Debug -lX11 -lXext -Wl,--no-as-needed -lDeskManagerDll -lpthread -o CLI_DeskManager
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 0 a un index de symbole 11 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 1 a un index de symbole 12 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 2 a un index de symbole 2 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 3 a un index de symbole 2 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 4 a un index de symbole 11 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 5 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 6 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 7 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 8 a un index de symbole 12 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 9 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 10 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 11 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 12 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 13 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 14 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 15 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 16 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 17 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 18 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 19 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 20 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 21 a un index de symbole 22 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): réadressage 0 a un index de symbole 2 invalide
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: dans la fonction « _start »:
(.text+0x18): référence indéfinie vers « main »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [CLI_DeskManager] Erreur 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is slightly unclear what you are trying to achieve, are you trying to create a shared library or are you simply trying to use one?

The Code::blocks log hints at the second option, if that is the case I notice that you have libDeskManagerDll.so in the Code::blocks log and -lDeskManager in the makefile, for them to be the same I would have expected that to be -lDeskManagerDll

also this line seems odd to me

```
@$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $<
```

I would have expected it to look like

```
@$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $< -o $@
```

If this does not resolve the problem could you remove the @ signs at the beginning of lines in the makefile and post the full output of make?

**UPDATE**

From your update it is clear that the make does not include the object files in the linking command. On closer inspection the line

```
SRCS = main.cpp shell.cpp
```

defines the source files which you then are trying to use with

```
OBJS      = $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)
```

changing that line to

```
OBJS      = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
```

should bring you closer to what you want

Comment: I am trying to use a static library. I tried what you said, I edited my question with the new Makefile and the full output of make.